# Function observer in livedata does not work

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I'm trying to get the response from Api with the Post method(retrofit). But the Observer doesn't work. I don't understand this error. even though I implemented it in the login activity, and it worked. the difference is this is done in fragments. \n Can you help me?

Note: I used KOIN for DI. I tried initiating the viewmodel with viewModel () and shareViewModel (). but they are no different

here I attach a snippet of the code:
Fragment.kt

```
viewModel.getKpp()?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<KppResponse> {kpp ->
                progress_bar_kpp.visibility = View.GONE             //don't work from here
                if (kpp.status == "false"){
                    tv_data_not_found.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                } else {
                    kppAdapter.setKpp(kpp.data)
                    kppAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }                                                   //up to here

            })

            with(rv_kpp){
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
                setHasFixedSize(true)
                adapter = kppAdapter
            }
```

ViewModel.kt:

```
fun getKpp(): LiveData<KppResponse>? = dataRepository.getKppPost(nip, jabatan, unit)
```

Repository.kt:

```
override fun getKgbPost(nip: String, jabatan: String, unit: String): LiveData<KgbResponse>? {
    val kgbResult = MutableLiveData<KgbResponse>()
    remoteDatasource.getDataKgbPost(object : RemoteDatasource.KgbPostCallback{
        override fun onResponse(kgb: KgbResponse?) {
            kgbResult.postValue(kgb)
        }

        override fun throwable(t: Throwable) {
            if (t.localizedMessage != null) {
                Timber.e(t.localizedMessage!!)
            }
        }

    }, nip, jabatan, unit)
    return kgbResult
}
```

and in logcat I see that "POST" was successful. and provide response as follows:
[Screenshot Response in Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ3Cr.png)

Comment: Can you add a log statement before `postValue()` and see if it prints? And ensure that `getKgbPost()` is not called more than once since you are creating `LiveData` object every time. I would suggest creating a member variable instead!

Comment: when I provide "log" before postvalue, the log is not printed. Why did it happen?

Comment: You need to check within your `remoteDataSource` object. Probably you should do the same exercise of adding a log statement wherever the callback is called.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. it turns out that the problem is in the model. I thought I should relearn using Timber. The error log from Timber doesn't appear (or isn't visible to me). so that makes it difficult for me.